# FastAPI avoid multiple connections to Database pymongo

Tags: python, database, pymongo, fastapi

I decided to give FastAPI go today. My understanding is that I should only have one connection to the database so I can easily close it on shutdown (maybe someone can shed light on this).

Originally I had a `get_db()` function and in my routes (multiple files) I was calling this function. My question is how correct is my implementation now (code shown below).

database.py

```
# Make a database class the only connects once
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = None

    def connect(self) -> Database:
        if self.db is None:
            uri = os.environ.get("TEST_MONGO_URI")
            client = MongoClient(uri, tls=True)
            self.db = client.get_database("development")
        return self.db

    def disconnect(self):
        if self.db is not None:
            self.db.client.close()
            self.db = None


# Import this instance into router files
database_instance = Database()
```

user_router.py

```
@user_router.get("/api/users")
async def get_users(db: Database=Depends(database.connect)):
    """
    Returns all users found in users collection
    """
    collection = db.get_collection("users")
    users = [UserOut(**user) for user in collection.find({})]
    return {"data": users}
```

Closing the connection in main.py

```
app.include_router(user_router)

@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():
    db.disconnect()
```

Am I totally wrong, what's the best way to handle this? Should I avoid multiple connections or is it ok? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connections would normally be handled as part of sessions. It's not correct that your application only has _one_ connection to a database at any one time because you might have multiple clients. What's important is that connections are closed as soon as they're no longer needed

Comment: I never thought of it that way. Just on closing the connection when not needed. Should that be done in the route, after querying the database or adding another user to the database?

Comment: Try to use motor driver for mongo